# Booting Android Device on AlarmManager Call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am building an Android Alarm Applicaion, and used following code for Main Calling Class:

```
   AlarmManager inst_alarm= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
   Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Alarm.class);
   pintent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
   inst_alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pintent);  

  //"cal" is reference of calendar class to get saved time in millisecond.
```

for Service Class:

```
public class Alarm extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

    Uri uri_alarm= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

    if(uri_alarm==null)
    {           uri_alarm=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone_alarm=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(c, uri_alarm);
    ringtone_alarm.play();
        }
}
```

This code work fine but i have few quesions.

Question: 1) Is it possible to alarm bell on scheduled time if android device is switched off(device get power on automatically to ring bell on saved time) as in default application of android device does.

2) Suppose i saved alarm after 8 minutes exactly and i restart my device then alarm start ringing immediately after boot(Because i have used "bootcomplete" for receiver in manifest) but i want to play alarm after 8 minutes exactly not on reboot.(I have saved alarm in shared-preference but how to use it on reboot)

EDIT: Can I use "Power Manager" class or any other class to handle above mentioned situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible...

No, not from complete power off.  You're most likely referring to screen being off and the device in low power state.  If the device is turned completely off then alarms cannot wake it.  The default Android clock app just wakes it from sleep.  If you'd like to wake up the screen and play sound, you'll have to create a `Service` which can be activated via your `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and have it start the appropriate UI.  If you do not, then the system can go right back to seep when your `onReceive()` is done.

> 2) ...want to play 8 minutes after...

What you're likely seeing is a previous expiration of your Alarm firing and you're waking up the device (not powering it on.)  Alarms are not retained across power cycles or reboots.  If you wish to have them stick around after a true reboot, then you'd have to manage that yourself.  The `PowerManager` and `AlarmManager` do not provide such a facility.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), if you're talking about complete shutdowns, it's unfortunately impossible. There is no way to do this without specialized hardware (and its corresponding software interface to your app).

For (2), you can do something clever. For example, persistently store the timestamp whenever the device restarts/turns off (you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` in addition to your `BOOT_COMPLETE`) when you have a pending alarm bell, and use that information on reboot/boot to resume (or stop, depending on the time difference and the alarm bell's "timer") or otherwise re-sync your pending alarm bell logic.

And for your `PowerManager` question, again if we're talking about complete shutdowns, unfortunately the answer is no.

`PowerManager` is used to mainly prevent the device from going into deep sleep. Remember, Android devices turn off their CPU's some time after they are locked, preventing your app from doing calculations/processes. This is essentially what the notion of "wakelocks" is about.

Comment: 1) Ok, but how does default alarm clock in android device do(Automatically power on and ring alarm at saved time if device is switched OFF) it ? 
2) How can i know if alarm is pending or not ?

Comment: 1) According to [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/does-the-alarm-work-when-my-phone-is-turned-off), the phone alarm will not work when the phone is shut down. Which is expected since literally no process is running when the device is shut down.

Comment: 2) When I say "pending alarm bells", I meant any of your "alarm bells" that are supposed to go off in the future. Basically the idea is to store the system time whenever the phone turns off and the user has set an "alarm bell" to go off. So when the phone boots up, you'll know how much time has passed, and from there you can sync your "alarm bell" logic so it would go off at the right time. You'll need persistent storage (look up `sqlite` usage in Android, or you can write information into a file. Persistence is key here, since it means the data will survive reboots).

Comment: "For (1), if you're talking about complete shutdowns, it's unfortunately impossible."  I would not say unfortunately.  If this were not the case, that would mean there would be no way to completely turn off the device (except perhaps removing the battery), which as a user I would not appreciate.